# How to disable Automake's test-driver script

Tags: testing, automake

Our project uses autoconf/automake for configuring and building. The building scripts work fine on Debian Squeeze and Wheezy (automake version 1.11.6), but don't work on Jessie, with a more recent version of automake (version 1.14.1). When I run `make distcheck` with the new automake version, it fails with

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/tmp/.../_build'
/bin/bash: ../autotools/test-driver: No such file or directory
```

Apparently, `test-driver` is a new script introduced by the recent automake version.

I tried to add `autotools/test-driver` into extra dependencies, but if it's present, `distcheck` fails with

```
.../_build/../autotools/test-driver: the following mandatory options are missing:
      --test-name --log-file --trs-file
```

I'd appreciate any ideas how I could either update my build scripts to work with the new version or how to disable this new automake behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Run `automake -a` at the top-level. Usually you should have a `bootstrap` script that invokes autotools with the correct flags for clean repository checkouts, or for when you make drastic changes to your build system.

And there's no need to set dependencies, unless you are custom-generating `test-driver` from a template or something.

Comment: This is what we currently have. We run `aclocal -I autotools`, then `autoconf` and then `automake --add-missing`. This works for the standard compilation, but fails for `make distcheck`.

Comment: @PetrPudlák then try from a clean checkout of the sources. Automake will install `test-driver` as soon as it finds a line describing a test (i.e. `TEST = someprogram`).